# How to extract links in span elements in a table using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

How to I extract links in `span` elements in a table in Selenium?

```
<table id="tabABC">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id="randomidIdontknow">
                 <a style="color: red" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">FancyLink</a>
             </span>
        </td>
</table>
```

I am trying to validate if the links in all the rows in the table is correct. For that, I am trying to extract the text info as below:

```
IWebElement mytab = Context.CurrentDriver.FindElement(By.Id("tabABC"));
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> myRows = mytab.FindElements(By.XPath(".//tbody/tr"));

foreach (var myRow in myRows ) 
{
    var myCol = myRow .FindElements(By.XPath(".//td"));
    var res = myRow .FindElement(By.XPath(".//td[0]")).Text;
}
```

(There would be only one `span` element in a column. )

Answer (score 1):

```
var tableElem = driver.FindElement(By.Id("tabABC"));

var linkElems = tableElem.FindElements(By.Tag("a"));

var links = linkElems.Select(x => x.GetAttribute("href")).ToList()
```

**In case it doesn't let you get the 'a' tag directly from table**

```
var spanElems = tableElem.FindElements(By.Tag("span"));

var linkElems = spanElems.SelectMany(x => x.FindElements(By.Tag("a"));

var links = linkElems.Select(x => x.GetAttribute("href")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The get all the link elements from column 1 and then extract the link with `GetAttribute`

```c#
var linkElements = mytab.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#tabABC tr > td[1] a[href]"));

foreach (var linkElement in linkElements ) 
{
    var link = linkElement.GetAttribute("href");
}
```